# How to start new intent when app is terminated

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application there's a button that takes me from an activity to another, however when I terminate the activity manually (in android studio) or if I leave the app for a long time in background in the phone stops working it closes my app and restarts it, without any error in the log monitor, please Help.

**Normal Scenario:**
1- In activity A.
2- Click on Button.
3- Goes to activity B.

**After app is on hold:**
1- Activity A.
2- Click on Button.
3- App exits and Restarts.
4- Click on Button.
5- Goes to Activity B.

**Log monitor:**

```
 08-07 09:11:38.769 707-707/com.ids.a3090 I/Timeline: Timeline: 
 Activity_launch_request id:com.ids.a3090 time:30319261
 08-07 09:11:38.781 707-724/com.ids.a3090 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 
 134714354
 08-07 09:11:38.783 707-724/com.ids.a3090 I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and 
 thus will not be used
 08-07 09:11:38.786 707-724/com.ids.a3090 D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e,      
 Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1947, _sc=PostsFeedActivity, 
_si=-8454969789890054863}]
08-07 09:11:38.794 707-707/com.ids.a3090 V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-07 09:11:38.801 707-707/com.ids.a3090 D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx]
[generateLayout] setLGNavigationBarColor : colors=0xff000000
08-07 09:11:38.801 707-707/com.ids.a3090 I/PhoneWindow: 
[setLGNavigationBarColor] color=0x ff000000
08-07 09:11:38.866 707-707/com.ids.a3090 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-07 09:11:40.874 707-707/com.ids.a3090 I/art: System.exit called, status: 2
08-07 09:11:40.874 707-707/com.ids.a3090 I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 2, cleanup skipped.
```

**The function:**

```
 public void showDrawer(View v){

    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(PostsFeedActivity.this, LandingActivity.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After debugging, the second activity is being started without setContentView(..) and then the activity exits.

Comment: Share manifest.xml

Comment: first of all use nearest context here like v.getContext() - [each context is different and is used for different thing) in your case you need a activity context (having token from activity ) view already has this context .. so it will be enough to call new Intent(v.getContext(),Component.class), second post rest of code in second activity to debug yr problem or better push source to some git repo (if you know how):)